# After installing a module, I can't login to my back-end

Tags: magento2.2, login, backend, fatal-error

I can get to the login page, but as I am trying to login, I am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getNext() on null in /home/geekcoreco/public_html/generated/code/Magento/User/Model/User/Interceptor.php:529 Stack trace:

```
#0 /home/geekcoreco/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Locale/Manager.php(96): Magento\User\Model\User\Interceptor->getInterfaceLocale() 
#1 /home/geekcoreco/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Locale/Resolver.php(77): Magento\Backend\Model\Locale\Manager->getUserInterfaceLocale() 
#2 /home/geekcoreco/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Locale/Resolver.php(65): Magento\Backend\Model\Locale\Resolver->setLocale(NULL) 
#3 /home/geekcoreco/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Locale/Resolver.php(60): Magento\Framework\Locale\Resolver->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Config), 'general/locale/...', 'store', NULL) 
#4 /home/geekcoreco/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(111): Magento\Backend\Model\Locale\Resolver->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Config), 'general in /home/geekcoreco/public_html/generated/code/Magento/User/Model/User/Interceptor.php on line 529
```

I've tried everything, I'm a bit lost now.
Any help would be very much appreciated. FYI the module I recently installed is **Magstore Google Shopping** module.

Running Magento v2.2.5

Comment: Disable the module doesn't help?

Comment: Just run php bin/magento setup:di:compile command then error still showing then search for getNext() funtion its getting null data so just add condition before that function for if(!empty(data)) then call that function

Answer (score 1):

Please run all the below commands:

> rm -rf generated/* var/cache/* var/page_cache/*
>
> php bin/magento s:up
>
> php bin/magento s:s:d -f
>
> php bin/magento c:c
>
> php bin/magento c:f

and check

Answer (score 1):

It is because your **last deployment** is having **different (old) code** there into your **generated & cache** folders it happens sometime that the **generated code** & the code into **view_processed** folder **doesn't get overwritten**. It is because of the **old dependency injection** so, whenever you are installing the modules with new **dependency injection** i.e. some changes with the **`di.xml`** files then must **remove the old dependency files** & let the Magento **rebuild/regenerate the new files** with the **latest dependency injection**.

To achieve this please run the below commands from the directory of your **magento_root** from the terminal.

> ```
>    rm -rf generated/ var/view_preprocessed/ var/composer_home/cache/
> var/cache/ var/page_cache/
>
> php bin/magento maintenance:enable
>
> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento setup:di:compile
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
>
> php bin/magento maintenance:disable
>
> php bin/magento cache:flush
> ```

Or you can run the above commands with their **abbreviated versions** as follows.

> ```
> php bin/magento ma:e  
>
> php bin/magento s:up
>
> php bin/magento s:d:c
>
> php bin/magento s:s:d -f
>
> php bin/magento ma:d
>
> php bin/magento c:f
> ```

Comment: Hi There,
I tried the above, but I get the following error:
rm: cannot remove `generated/code/Magento/Framework': Directory not empty

Any more ideas?

Comment: Your **generated** folder is not get deleted please delete it completely or comment it by simply adding extra character at the suffix or prefix like -> **generated__** or **__generated** & retry with the above 4 deployment commands!

Comment: Hi, I deleted Generated using FTP, then ran the commands. However I get the following error when running the Compile command.

The directory "/home/geekcoreco/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework" cannot be deleted Warning!rmdir(/home/geekcoreco/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework): Directory not empty

Comment: Okay so delete the folder & run the compile command first then the upgrade command

Comment: I think the problem is, it regenerates before I can run the command.

Comment: Aha! It worked!
I needed to enter Maintenance mode. That was all.
Thank you so much!